# Docker appears to be running but getting error: localhost didn't send any data

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, docker, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy a React-Flask application with PostgreSQL in Heroku, but I am receiving a H10: App Crashed error. When running the Docker image locally, I also get an error saying localhost did not send any data. Docker says it is running, but it does not display anything when going to localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000. I am at a loss for what is going wrong here.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /react-app
COPY react-app/. .

# You have to set this because it should be set during build time.
ENV REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://(blahblahblah).herokuapp.com/

# Build our React App
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM python:3.9

# Setup Flask environment
ENV FLASK_APP=app
ENV FLASK_ENV=production
ENV SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .
COPY --from=build-stage /react-app/build/* app/static/

# Install Python Dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install psycopg2

# Run flask environment
CMD gunicorn app:app
```

Docker Commands:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t react-app .
docker run --env-file .env  --rm -p 8000:8000 react-app
```

Docker Build Output:

```
(project_alpha) project_alpha % docker build -f Dockerfile -t react-app .              
[+] Building 12.9s (17/17) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 639B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 105B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                                                                                               0.7s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12                                                                                                                                                  0.7s
 => [build-stage 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12@sha256:01627afeb110b3054ba4a1405541ca095c8bfca1cb6f2be9479c767a2711879e                                                                                0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:cfcc9ef77b6cf87f57327aacc6f9b50c7cdb4d7dd93662a36549f05b7403cd47                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.9s
 => => transferring context: 550.78kB                                                                                                                                                                       0.9s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/6] WORKDIR /var/www                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [stage-1 3/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                  0.3s
 => CACHED [build-stage 2/5] WORKDIR /react-app                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 3/5] COPY react-app/. .                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 4/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 5/5] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [stage-1 4/6] COPY --from=build-stage /react-app/build/* app/static/                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [stage-1 5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                       5.5s
 => [stage-1 6/6] RUN pip install psycopg2                                                                                                                                                                  5.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                      0.5s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                     0.5s
 => => writing image sha256:acbaf8cfb553dfd8aa9f791eaea06f9f6bc31f6d9b6d77e7a0e771b78f46855b                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/react-app
```

Docker Run Output:

```
(project_alpha) project_alpha % docker run --env-file .env  --rm -p 8000:8000 react-app
[2022-09-22 17:33:21 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-09-22 17:33:21 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7)
[2022-09-22 17:33:21 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-09-22 17:33:21 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
```

Folder Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YchWe.png

Comment: docker build gives me an error - `failed to compute cache key: "/react-app" not found: not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
[2022-09-22 17:33:21 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7)
```

Your process is only listening on the local interface. If you open a shell in the container and try to curl that url you will see it works.

You need to make your application listen on `0.0.0.0:8000` instead.

Comment: Thank you Mihai! I was able to change my gunicorn listening address by adding the --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 argument to my gunicorn cmd in Dockerfile.